# add table layout panel in the column of table lay out panel

Tags: vb.net, winforms

[image]hi i am working on windows form application.i want to create Table layout panel programatically like my image.so i given code like this in form load event

```
Dim dynamicTableLayoutPanel As New TableLayoutPanel()
    dynamicTableLayoutPanel.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(26, 300)
    dynamicTableLayoutPanel.Name = "TableLayoutPanel1"
    dynamicTableLayoutPanel.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(400, 100)
    dynamicTableLayoutPanel.TabIndex = 0
    dynamicTableLayoutPanel.CellBorderStyle = TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.Single
    Controls.Add(dynamicTableLayoutPanel)

    dynamicTableLayoutPanel.ColumnCount = 6
    dynamicTableLayoutPanel.RowCount = 2

    dynamicTableLayoutPanel.ColumnStyles.Add(New ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 30.0F))
    dynamicTableLayoutPanel.ColumnStyles.Add(New ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 30.0F))
    dynamicTableLayoutPanel.ColumnStyles.Add(New ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 30.0F))
    dynamicTableLayoutPanel.ColumnStyles.Add(New ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 30.0F))
    dynamicTableLayoutPanel.ColumnStyles.Add(New ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 30.0F))
    dynamicTableLayoutPanel.ColumnStyles.Add(New ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 50.0F))
    dynamicTableLayoutPanel.RowStyles.Add(New RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 52.0F))
    dynamicTableLayoutPanel.RowStyles.Add(New RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 44.0F))
```

in this 2nd row of last column i again added one more table lay out panel with two column.how i can write code code for this? what is the change i have to make in my code

Comment: Everything is fine, you just have to add columns and rows. Set the `CellBorderStyle` to `TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.Single` and you'll see it's there.

Comment: ok.sir ..i got it..but i want to create table layout panel somthing like this.i will edit my question with image

Answer (score 0):

Use Visual Studio Designer, to create what you want,
 and after save, open **yourForm.Designer.vb** and copy all what is in that file. 
And now you have the code to create programatically your table..

Have Fun !

Answer (score 0):

As CristiC777 said - if you go into your form's .Designer.vb after creating what you want visually you should see a line of code to add the second TableLayoutPanel to your first like this:

```
    Me.TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(Me.TableLayoutPanel2, 5, 1)
```

The numbers in the arguments denote which column and row to add it to.